# how to copy all message and add some field with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I need to copy the entire xml message and add a few fields, but at the moment of applying the xslt only copy me the values and not the name of the tag, can you help me please

this is de input xml

```
<Xmlroot>
    <headerIn>
        <field1>hello</field1>
        <field2>world</field2>
    </headerIn>
</Xmlroot>
```

i need this response

```
<Xmlroot>
    <headerIn>
        <field1>hello</field1>
        <field2>world</field2>
        <other>nice</other>
    </headerIn>
</Xmlroot>
```

i have this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tns" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="headerIn">
    <headerIn>
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </headerIn>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I obtain this output

```
<Xmlroot>
    <headerIn xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tns">hello
    world
    </headerIn>
</Xmlroot>
```

Comment: The output you claim is not the output obtained by running your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this XSL-template which copies all nodes and simply adds the element `<other>nice</other>` at the appropriate place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tns" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="headerIn">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <other>nice</other>  <!-- replace this line with whatever element you want to add -->
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a valid XSLT for transforming the values and the name.  You can then add the additional output you want to create.  I have added one additional element `<other>` as you showed in your example. The key for preserving the element name is use of `{local-name()}`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="headerIn">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:element name="other">nice</xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry but with this xsl i have the same problem.

Comment: with this xsl i can copy all message and add a field

Comment: @Kalin666 your comments are not clear. So this did work for you?  If it did, please feel free to mark it as a suitable answer.